# Creatting a BufferedImage with Retina support

Tags: java, image, servlets

I'm using latest JDK 7u45 for my development.When I create a simple servlet which used for generating verification code,I found out the image is rather blurred.The image looks just like this:[image: verification code image]

The image is of rather poor quality,and look really poor with my Macbook pro retina display.
The Code I'm using for creating the BufferedImage is rather simple:

```
    public static BufferedImage getImage() {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(IMAGE_WIDTH,IMAGE_HEIGHT,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics graphics = image.getGraphics();
        drawRandomNumber((Graphics2D)graphics);

        return image;
    }

    private static void drawRandomNumber(Graphics2D graphics) {
        graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
        graphics.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD|Font.ITALIC,RANDOM_NUMBER_FONT_SIZE));
        char lch = 'a',hch = 'z';
        char lcach = 'A',hcach = 'Z';
        int x = RANDOM_NUMBER_START_X;
        for (int i = 0;i < RANDOM_NUMBER_NUM;i++) {
            char ch = new Random().nextBoolean() ?
                    (char)(new Random().nextInt(hch - lch) + lch) :
                    (char)(new Random().nextInt(hcach - lcach) + lcach);

            int degree = new Random().nextInt() % 30;
            graphics.rotate(degree * Math.PI / 180,x,RANDOM_NUMBER_START_Y);
            graphics.drawString(ch + "",x,RANDOM_NUMBER_START_Y);
            graphics.rotate(-degree * Math.PI / 180,x,RANDOM_NUMBER_START_Y);
            x += 60;
        }
    }
```

And the code that writes the image to the servlet:

```
ImageIO.write(image, "png", response.getOutputStream());
```

I just want to know If I want to create a high quality image which support HDPI display,what should I do?Is there any way to produce high quality image with java code?I tried many ways but they seem to help nothing.

Comment: You should not use the `Random` class like you do in your code.  Store  the generator in a variable so you can re-use it.   Also it is preferable to call `nextInt(30)` instead of doing the modulo operation.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)

Answer (score 0):

```
private float xScaleFactor, yScaleFactor = ...;
    private BufferedImage originalImage = ...;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        int newW = (int)(originalImage.getWidth() * xScaleFactor);
        int newH = (int)(originalImage.getHeight() * yScaleFactor);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g2.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, newW, newH, null);
    }
```

Comment: do you want to explain your answer a bit?

Comment: Please have a look at this link->https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html

Comment: you mean scale the image to get better quality?Can't I create a high quality image while I'm creating the BufferedImage?